# How to match bounded-repeat as only n and m times

Tags: c++, regex, boost

Based on [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/regex/doc/syntax_perl.html)

```
a{n}  Matches 'a' repeated exactly n times.

a{n,}  Matches 'a' repeated n or more times.

a{n, m}  Matches 'a' repeated between n and m times inclusive.
```

**Question**> How to match 'a' repeated exactly n or m times?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

very simple : `a{n}|a{m}`   :)

ok ?

Comment: Indeed this seems to be the only way (after limited research) I wish there was a more concise way.  Imagine that instead of 'a' you have a complicated character set, its tedious to repeat so many times...

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this would do the trick:

```
a{n}|a{m}
```

However, I'm not sure what you are expecting to get if you match a{m}: do you also want a{n} to match? And what about if a{n} fits twice in a{m}?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to comment on the above answers (since this falls along the lines of the question posed by Mosty Mostacho, but couldn't so I'll just add another answer.

I was trying to accomplish the same thing as OP and the answers were very helpful:

```
a{n}|a{m}
```

So just in case this will help anyone else out: I was trying match a year string that's either 2 or 4 digits.
This didn't work since (I'm guessing) regexp matches the \d{2} and moved on:

```
\d{2}|\d{4}
```

But this worked:

```
\d{4}|\d{2}
```

Maybe this is obvious to other.  But just my $0.02.